# Can you extend the record type similar to an extension method?

Tags: c#, .net, record

Lets say as it happens to be the case, that all my models/poco's are records.  It just so happens we find it useful in many cases to convert our models to json.  So that we don't have to override the .ToString() in every model an entitybase record was created with the following method and inherited by the rest of the models:

```
public record EntityBase
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
    }
}
```

But I wondered if there were a way to modify or extend the record or class type almost similar to an extension method.

```
    // record / class are not valid types here
    public static string ToString(this record value)
        => System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);
    
    // this works but I want to constrain it to records and non generic methods do not allow constraints
    public static string ToString(this object value)
        => System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);
```

I can think of a million reasons it might be a bad idea but I am curious if it possible?  Is there another or better way to modify these types if its possible?

Comment: `record` isn't a type. The way to do this would be to write a generic method and constrain the generic type parameter to be a `record`. I'm not sure whether that's actually possible though. You have long been able to constrain generic types to be `structure` or `class` but I've not heard of `record` being added to that list and never tried it myself.

Comment: Don't bake serialization into your classes. This may feel like a good idea, but it's not a primary concern of the class, not even for DTOs, and it wil bind you to that specific serialization, whether it's the format or the library. If you need to switch, you shouldn't have to change it in these classes.

Comment: That's not to say you can't add metadata, like `[JsonPropertyName(...)]`. You could add that, `[XmlElement(...)]`, or anything else. Those can co-exist, but the actual serialization used should be selected externally.

Comment: Are you sure the last one works? I think the compiler will resolve `something.ToString()` to `Object.ToString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record):

> There's no generic constraint that requires a type to be a record. Records satisfy either the class or struct constraint. To make a constraint on a specific hierarchy of record types, put the constraint on the base record as you would a base class.

So you could define an abstract base entity:

```
public abstract record BaseEntity();
```

Derive all your records from it:

```
public record MyEntity(...) : BaseEntity();
```

Then define your extension method this way:

```
public static ToJson<T>(this T source) where T : BaseEntity
{
    return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(source);
}
```

But of course if you're going to do that, you may as well put it in BaseEntity.

```
public abstract record BaseEntity()
{
    public override string ToString() => System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
}
```